# Jenkins CLI who-am-i command always reporting anonymous

Tags: authentication, jenkins, command-line-interface

I have a user called "jenkins" that has id_rsa.pub key in it's configuration. When I attempt to run `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar who-am-i` it always reports back:

`Authenticated as: anonymous
Authorities:`

This makes me think it's failing to authenticate and defaulting to anonymous.

Any ideas?

Comment: The [docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) mention that on an auth failure, Jenkins attempts to run the command as the anonymous user. What happens if you explicitly ask it to use the private key using the `-i` option? Unfortunately the site does not mention any verbosity switch on the CLI...

Comment: Still the same issue. What I ended up doing was configure Jenkins to act as an ssh server. After that I was able to ssh using the configured port and issues similar CLI commands.

e.g.
{ssh -p 16234 <jenkinsServer> who-am-I}

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to specify that you want to connect via SSH and specify the username.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://your-jenkins-server/jenkins/ -ssh -user "your-user" who-am-i
```

You will also have to enable the SSH server in Jenkins (Configure Global Security -> SSH Server). Official wiki article:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+SSH